# Manage various git project in a symfony2 project

Tags: git, symfony, github, project-management

Let's say we've had cloned a handful of project in github and want to use them in the current symfony2 project. For instance : jquery, jqueryui, datatables (jquery plugin), various other jquery plugins and so on.
The reason why we clone them is to be able to alter the projects to fit our needs, and to request a pull on github, anyway...

At this point we have different remote addresses, but they all land in the same project. What are best practices to maintain such big and tangled project?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a lot of frontend libraries which are not bound directly to your Symfony2 project. My advice to manage such dependencies is to use the [YEOMAN](http://yeoman.io/) workflow and specifically to use [Bower](http://bower.io/) to register your own packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding another package manager to the pit seems to be a little overkill (there is already composer and git), maybe a better solution is to have a separate namespace/bundle holding  various packages and manage them with git-submodules.

Comment: Well yes, if the library need in some way to interact with the server side environment I'm agree with you (see for example one of the Twitter Bootstrap bundle implementation which give us integration with Symfony2 forms). But if you need to use the library "as is" in my opinion is worth to add your SF2 another level of complexity introducing a bundle whose purpose is only to serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something similar to http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/